# how to calculate the fixed monthly payment of credit card

Tags: python, loops

How do I continue the following loop until I find `mmp = 310`?  So far, with my code the furthest I can go is `mmp = 240`. Do you think I should have one more `if` statement?

```
balance = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
mir = annualInterestRate/12
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04


rb = balance
mmp = 0
Month = 1
while Month <= 12: 
    print('Month:' + str(Month))  
    mmp = mmp + 10
    print('Minimum monthly payment:' + str(mmp))
    ub = rb - mmp
    rb = round(ub + (annualInterestRate/12 * ub), 2)
    Month = Month + 1 
    print('Remaining balance:' + str(rb))
if rb > 0:
    rb = balance
    Month = 1
    while Month <= 12:
        print('Month:' + str(Month)) 
        mmp = mmp + 10
        print('Minimum monthly payment:' + str(mmp))
        ub = rb - mmp
        rb = round(ub + (annualInterestRate/12 * ub), 2)
        Month = Month + 1 
        print('Remaining balance:' + str(rb))

else:
    print('Lowest Payment:' + str(mmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while Month <= 12:`, you could use `while mmp < 310:` if you just want to reach that number. Or `while rb > 0:` if you want to continue looping until everything is paid.

If looping over the months is a requirement (btw, it's [generally appreciated here if you mention that your question is homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)), you could add an outer loop for years:

```
year = 1
while rb > 0:
    month = 1
    while month <= 12:
        # do stuff
        month = month + 1
    year = year + 1
```

Comment: Yes it is homework problem and i got stick very badly. One more thing is it has to be `1 year` only and so basically i had to calculate how much is the `mmp` at which `rb < 0` for `12` months.